# How to write these two (ANSI) SQL queries?

Tags: sql

I have a table with data that looks like this:

```
create table demo_patient_info (
  attend timestamp,  
  patient_id int, 
  blood_pressure double
);
```

I would like to write (preferably ANSI) SQL queries that allow me to do the following:

### query1:

return the difference between bp of all patients with each other (using a WHERE clause to restrict the number of rows returned in the cartesian product)

### query2:

return the difference between bp of each patient and one specific (i.e. specified) patient in the table

Comment: "blood_pressure double" not intended?!

Comment: Hehe ... Freudian slip ... zing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1)

```
SELECT 
    t1.patient_id
   ,t2.patient_id
   ,t1.blood_pressure - t2.blood_pressure as bp_diff
FROM
   demo_patient_info t1
CROSS JOIN
   demo_patient_info t2
WHERE
   t1.patient_id < t2.patient_id
```

2)

```
SELECT 
    t1.patient_id
   ,t2.patient_id
   ,t1.blood_pressure - t2.blood_pressure as bp_diff
FROM
   demo_patient_info t1
CROSS JOIN
   demo_patient_info t2
WHERE 
   t2.patient_id = 1
```

This will likely give two rows for each match though, which may or may not be OK

edit:  `WHERE t1.patient_id < t2.patient_id` in query 1 is there to prevent the following, duplication and self matching

```
ID1 ID2  diff 
1    2    1.4 
2    1    1.4 
1    1     0
```

thanks to Jonathan Leffler for the hint :)

Comment: Pure SQL poetry. I havent tried it out yet. But it is aesthesticly pleasing (if that makes sense)

Comment: Not sure I understand. Why will it give two rows for each match?. Assuming it does though, can I not use a SELECT DISTINCT to make sure the rows are unique?

Comment: The CROSS JOIN should be filtered with a condition - usually t1.patient_id < t2.patient_id to remove self-comparisons and to list each pair just once.